# trying to use json array to insert data in sql with c# but still getting Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue error?

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing an array of JSON data from client-side to server-side (c#). However when I try to insert this data into a SQL table I'm having this `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` just at the moment of the query execution.

Here's the code I have so far:

Client (js);

```
var json = [];

var Firstcotizacion = {
    idCotizacion: "111111",
    idProyecto: "8047",
    nombreProyecto: "Edificio Caiquen",
    idProducto: "MLC462815278"
}


var Secondcotizacion = {
    idCotizacion: "222222",
    idProyecto: "1234",
    nombreProyecto: "Edificio malbec",
    idProducto: "MLC29870FD"
}


json.push(Firstcotizacion)
json.push(Secondcotizacion)

$.post("../Ajax/GuardaCotizacionesPI", { json: JSON.stringify(json) }, function (data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Server-side (C#):

```
public string GuardarCotizacion(string json)
{
    string SP_INSERTA_COTIZACIONPI = "SVI_CPI_COTIZACION_PI";
    dynamic cotizaciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    foreach (var cotizacion in cotizaciones)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Inventa.PazCorp.Data.BaseDatos.StringConexionGestionContactos(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"].ToString())))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SP_INSERTA_COTIZACIONPI, conexion))
            {
                comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDCOTIZACION", cotizacion.idCotizacion);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDPROYECTO", cotizacion.idProyecto);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("NOMBRE_PROYECTO", cotizacion.nombreProyecto);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDPRODUCTO", cotizacion.idProducto);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Here is where the error appears
            }
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You make a call to `/Ajax/GuardaCotizacionesPI` but then you show a method called `GuardarCotizacion`. How is the 1st connected to the 2nd?

Comment: Why are you deserialising to `dynamic` though? Use a concrete class and all this goes away. Also, every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies.

Comment: @peterB they are connected by a controller

Comment: @DavidG : Is telling the purest truth. Why are you using dynamic ? You should use explicit type. Try implementing a List<Cotizacion> in a Cotizaciones class, and use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cotizaciones>(json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use the non-generic version of [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm), JSON.Net will deserialise everything to it's own objects like `JObject` and `JValue`. And because you are hiding all of that by using `dynamic`, you are susceptible to all sorts of runtime errors.

However, if you use a concrete class though, you will get type-safe code. For example:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public string idCotizacion { get; set; }
    public string idProyecto { get; set; }
    public string nombreProyecto { get; set; }
    public string idProducto { get; set; }
}
```

Now use the [generic method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm):

```
var cotizaciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyThing>>(json);
```

And the rest of your code should fit right in, but is now much clearer and safe.

As an aside, you should not be using [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, I would implement a Cotizacion class :

```
public class Cotizacion {
   public string idCotizacion {get; set;}
   public string idProyecto {get; set;}
   public string nombreProyecto {get; set;}
   public string idProducto{get; set;}
}
```

And then do something like :

```
public string GuardarCotizacion(string json)
        {

            string SP_INSERTA_COTIZACIONPI = "SVI_CPI_COTIZACION_PI";
            var cotizaciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cotizacion>>(json);

            foreach (var cotizacion in cotizaciones)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Inventa.PazCorp.Data.BaseDatos.StringConexionGestionContactos(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"].ToString())))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SP_INSERTA_COTIZACIONPI, conexion))
                    {
                        comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDCOTIZACION", cotizacion.idCotizacion);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDPROYECTO", cotizacion.idProyecto);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("NOMBRE_PROYECTO", cotizacion.nombreProyecto);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDPRODUCTO", cotizacion.idProducto);
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Here is where the error appears
                    }
                }
            }
            return json;
        }
```